# jQuery menu links mouseout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have menu links on a page that lie across the top horizontally.

When I hover on a particular link, a div appears below it showing child divs. for this I used jQuery hover function.

Now, when I mouseout of the link, the div that appeared should dissappear, I used mouseout function to do that.

My problem is, when I am leaving the link to go into one of the child links, it should not dissappear. How do I achieve this?

as I move my mouse towards the child links, as soon as I moouseout of the parent link, the child div dissappears.

Comment: post your html. or make a jsfiddle

Comment: Surround the link object and the div by another div object and apply the hover event on this surrounding block. As [jQuery hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) offers two parameters, the mouseOut callback is not needed. Be sure to that the css property display is none for the dropdown area when not visible, so the new surrounding div has got the same size as the link element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give them(menu and layers) the same class.
Sample code:

```
<div class="menu keep">
<div class="layer keep">Layer1</div>
<div class="layer keep">Layer2</div>
<div class="layer keep">Layer2</div>
<div class="layer keep">Layer3</div>
</div>
```

and in JQuery:

```
$(".keep").on("mouseenter",function(){
$(".layer").show();
});
$(".keep").on("mouseleave",function(){
$(".layer").hide();
});
```